# Look ahead and look behind not working for quanteda dictionary

Tags: r, regex, quanteda

I am trying to set up a quanteda dictionary which contains many overlapping terms. I believe using regex look ahead/look behind could be a way to solve this and avoid false hits, but I must be doing something wrong.

```
text <- c("guinea", "equatorial guinea", "guinea bissau")
dict <- dictionary(list(guinea="guinea"))
dfm <- dfm(text, dictionary=dict, valuetype="regex")
colSums(dfm)              
dict2 <- dictionary(list(guinea="(?<!equatorial[[:space:]])guinea"))
dfm2 <- dfm(text, dictionary=dict2, valuetype="regex")
colSums(dfm2)
dict3 <- dictionary(list(guinea="guinea(?![[:space:]]bissau)"))
dfm3 <- dfm(text, dictionary=dict3, valuetype="regex")
colSums(dfm3)
```

Expected results should be

```
# dfm1
colSums(dfm1)
guinea 
     3 
# dfm2
colSums(dfm2)
guinea 
     2
# dfm3 
colSums(dfm3)
guinea 
     2
```

But actual results are all = 3
Is this an issue with the look ahead/behind or with how the blank space is inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of regex matching does not work because patterns cannot span multiple tokens, and in the `dfm(x, dictionary = ...)` call, it is actually calling `tokens_lookup()` after tokenizing the text.

There is a much easier way to do this, which is simply to include the multi-word values in your dictionary.  So:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.3

text <- c("guinea", "equatorial guinea", "guinea bissau")

dict <- dictionary(list(guinea = "guinea"))
dict2 <- dictionary(list(guinea = "equatorial guinea"))
dict3 <- dictionary(list(guinea = "guinea bissau"))

dfm(text, dictionary = dict)
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (0.0% sparse).
## 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    guinea
##   text1      1
##   text2      1
##   text3      1

dfm(text, dictionary = dict2)
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (66.7% sparse).
## 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    guinea
##   text1      0
##   text2      1
##   text3      0

dfm(text, dictionary = dict3)
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (66.7% sparse).
## 3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
##        features
## docs    guinea
##   text1      0
##   text2      0
##   text3      1
```